# (g)make: Make A depend on B so that A rebuilds if B has changed, but don't rebuild B if it's out of date wrt its dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

Check out my Makefile below.  We have a set of graphs that are included in our paper.  These graphs can be auto-generated using python scripts.  But not all collaborators have the python tools (or need them).  What I'd like to do is add rules that lead to this behavior:

- An explicit "make graphs" is required to rebuild the graph PDFs (which are also tracked by git).
- If the graph PDFs are out of date (relative to their sources), a simple "make" will NOT attempt to rebuild them.  Only the main document may be rebuilt.
- If any graph PDFs have been updated LATER than the main document (either due to a pull or a "make graphs"), then a "make" will notice that the dependencies have changed and rebuild the document.
- If a graph PDF is missing (even if it can be generated by "make graphs"), it's okay for the "make" to just fail.

In searching for a solution, I have found out about "Order-only prerequisites."  But this is the converse of what I want.  With an order-only prereq, "make" would implicitly cause "make graphs" to happen, but it would not rebuild the document.  I don't want a "make graphs" to happen, but I DO want to rebuild the document.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

```
MAIN      = main

TEXFILES  = $(shell find . -name '*.tex')
BIBFILES  = $(shell find . -name '*.bib')
FIGURES   = $(shell find FIGS/ -name '*.pdf')
GRAPHS    = $(shell find GRAPHS/ -name '*.py' | sed -e 's/py/pdf/')

LATEX     = pdflatex
BIBTEX    = bibtex


default: $(MAIN).pdf

$(MAIN).pdf: $(FIGURES) $(TEXFILES) $(BIBFILES)
    $(LATEX) -output-format=pdf $(MAIN)
    $(BIBTEX) $(MAIN)
    $(LATEX) -output-format=pdf $(MAIN)
    $(LATEX) -output-format=pdf $(MAIN)

$(MAIN).ps: $(MAIN).pdf
    pdf2ps $(MAIN).pdf $(MAIN).ps

graphs: $(GRAPHS)

GRAPHS/%.pdf: GRAPHS/%.py
    cd GRAPHS; python2 $*.py; cd -

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.aux *.log *.bbl *.blg *.brf $(MAIN).dvi $(MAIN).ps $(MAIN).pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you have to do is ensure make doesn't know how to rebuild the graphs unless the `graphs` target was requested.  Something like this should be enough:

```
.PHONY: graphs
graphs: $(GRAPHS)

ifeq ($(filter graphs,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),graphs)
GRAPHS/%.pdf: GRAPHS/%.py
        cd GRAPHS; python2 $*.py; cd -
endif
```